# Redirect is giving me 2 address in the browser bar. So I am getting an error. Can't figure it out

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I am getting 2 address in the browser window so I am getting an error. This is on GoDaddy. I'm thinking maybe a change in the php might fix it because it seems to be bringing up the domain the redirect is coming from.

Example:
my site.com - trying to redirect to an external site after the submit button in the form is submitted.

It redirects me to:
http://www.mysite/ http://external_site
 instead of just:  external_site.com

Any help would be great as I am totally lost on this…

The redirect is in a hidden field in a form. It is using GoDaddy's php which is below:

```
<?php
$request_method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
if($request_method == "GET"){
  $query_vars = $_GET;
} elseif ($request_method == "POST"){
  $query_vars = $_POST;
}
reset($query_vars);
$t = date("U");

$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../data/gdform_" . $t;
$fp = fopen($file,"w");
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($query_vars)) {
 fputs($fp,"<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=$key START>\n");
 fputs($fp,"$val\n");
 fputs($fp,"<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=$key END>\n");
 if ($key == "redirect") { $landing_page = $val;}
}
fclose($fp);
if ($landing_page != ""){
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/$landing_page");
} else {
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/");
}


?>
```

Comment: The only two `headers` start with the location being your site.  I don't know the value of `$landing_page` to be able to tell you why, but if you are redirection to an external site: `header('location: http://www.google.com`);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` in the first header ...

```
<?php
    /* above your code */ 
    if ($landing_page != ""){
      header("Location: $landing_page");  // If the http:// is missing don't forget to add it
    } else {
      header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/");
    }
?>
```